# HTML & CSS Resizing

Tags: html, css

So I followed this tutorial on centering content, it's a two column layout. 
[Tutorial](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/)

Here is the code for the completed product:

https://jsfiddle.net/dppttuvn/

My problem is, as soon as I change the `#wrap` width and then `#main` and `#sidebar` width so it fills the `#wrap` width, the layout completly screws up. As shown in this link:

https://jsfiddle.net/dwzvoarv/

The sidebar isn't to the right of the main section.

Can someone briefly explain why this happens and also fix it?

Thank you! (I'm still learning web development clearly lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). By default, browsers separate padding and width, so basically the total width of your element is `padding + width`.

Lets say your element is `1000px`, with a `padding-left: 100px`. What the browser will do by default is paint the element as being `1100px` because that extra padding isn't included in the width (by default).

Add this selector to the top of your stylesheet...

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

...and what this is doing is telling every element on the page (thats what the `*` selector with no parent selectors does) and sets the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property of it to `border-box`, meaning that the browser will now respect the `width` property as the actual total width.

So now if you have a `1000px` element with `padding-left: 100px`, then the total width will still actually be `1000px` including that padding.

Answer (score 1):

You have to account for padding when you set widths. So to get 1000px you set #main to 700px and #sidebar to 300px. However since there is a 10px padding all around you have to subtract those pixels 10px left and 10px right. so your #main should be 680px and #sidebar should be 280px. Run this code in JS Fiddle and you can see it working.

```
         body,
     html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: #000;
        background: white;
     }

     #wrap {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #99c;
     }

     #header {
         padding:5px 10px;
         background:#ddd;
     }

     h1 {
         margin:0;
     }

     #nav {
         padding:5px 10px;
         background:#c99;
     }

     #main {
         float:left;
         width:680px;
         padding:10px;
         background:#9c9;
     }

     h2 {
         margin:0 0 1em;
     }

     #sidebar {
         float:right;
         width:280px;
         padding:10px;
         background:#99c;
     }

     #footer {
         clear:both;
         padding:5px 10px;
         background:#cc9;
     }

     #footer p {
         margin:0;
     }

     /* Navigation Bar */

     #nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
     }

     #nav li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the actual size of the divs is `width + padding + border`.
Use:

```
div{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

To get the desired behaviour. Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

---

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dwzvoarv/4/

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for your example, you can fix it by changing the wrap width to 1040px:

```
   #wrap {
        width: 1040px;   /*instead of 1000px*/
    }
```

width of wrap = width of main + width of column + padding of main (right and left) + padding of column (right and left)
= 700 + 300 + 20 + 20 = 1040px